# A way to extract from a DateTime value data without seconds

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I have an sql `DateTime` (ms sql server) and want to extract the same date without the seconds:
e.g. `2011-11-22 12:14:58.000` to become: `2011-11-22 12:14:00.000`

How can I do this? I was thinking to use `DATEADD` in combination with `DATEPART` but seems very error prone (besides performance issues)

Comment: In what way does this seem error-prone?

Comment: long and quite hard to write correctly ? :-)

Comment: is it that you want to hide seconds?? why are you providing seconds as 000 ALWAYS??

Comment: @Fahim I want to have 0 seconds because I want to group records from the same date/hour/minute

Answer (score 28, accepted):

For a solution that truncates using strings try this:

```
SELECT CAST(CONVERT(CHAR(16), GetDate(),20) AS datetime)
```

---

CHAR(16) works only if our variable is converted to *ODBC canonical* format, as shown above by using `20` as the format specifier.

```
DECLARE @date DateTime = '2011 Nov 22 12:14:55';
SELECT CONVERT(Char(16), @date ,20) AS datetime
```

Results:

```
| datetime         |
|------------------|
| 2011-11-22 12:14 |
```

Then you simply cast back to a DateTime type to continue using the value.

> **NOTE:** This is only viable for data types that do not carry TimeZone info.
>   Also type conversions to VarChar and back are usually *LESS* performant than using DateTime functions that use numeric operations internally.
>
> > Consider other solutions posted if performance is a concern or if you must retain timezone information.

Comment: This isn't a good answer. First of all, `CHAR(17)` has to be used instead, or the minutes will be wrong. Secondly, this method produces a type conversion warning.

Comment: I just wasted 1 hour of work asuming this query was correct :p Thank you, internet!

Comment: This answer is correct when using the input string shown in the example. It is however not correct if the field we are operating on is a DateTime object.

Comment: It's a fairly critical weakness not to be able to cope with a datetime. The text conversion is a starting point, but we need a more general solution. And it won't let me take back my upvote.

Comment: Fellow seekers, keep scrolling to t-clausen.dk's solution below.

Answer (score 71):

```
SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, yourcolumn), 0) FROM yourtable
```

This will be effective, if you don't want a slow conversion between datatypes.

Comment: Regarding the "Edit, best solution", casting like that will round to the nearest minute.  OP wants the seconds truncated, not rounded.  
Example showing the rounded result:
`DECLARE @myDate DATETIME = '2007-05-08 12:35:32'

SELECT  CAST(@myDate   AS smalldatetime)`

Comment: @Ojen you are absolutely right, well spotted. I removed that part of my answer

Answer (score 3):

```
DECLARE @TheDate DATETIME
SET @TheDate = '2011-11-22 12:14:58.000'

DATEADD(mi, DATEDIFF(mi, 0, @TheDate), 0)
```

In queries

```
/* ...all records in that minute; index-friendly expression */ 
WHERE TheDate BETWEEN DATEADD(mi, DATEDIFF(mi, 0, @TheDate), 0) 
                  AND DATEADD(mi, DATEDIFF(mi, 0, @TheDate) + 1, 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

Date and time needs carefully and not being converted as TEXT.

My personal solution:

```
    CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnDateTimeTruncated]
(
    @datetime DATETIME
)
RETURNS DATETIME
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN DATETIMEFROMPARTS ( year(@datetime), month(@datetime), day(@datetime), DATEPART(hh,@datetime), DATEPART(mi,@datetime), 0, 0)
END
```

Edited:

Regarding http://blog.waynesheffield.com/wayne/archive/2012/03/truncate-a-date-time-to-different-part/, DateAdd has a better performance.
Thanks to t-clausen.dk

Comment: DateTimeFromParts is not an effective solution. Found this [Link](http://blog.waynesheffield.com/wayne/archive/2012/03/truncate-a-date-time-to-different-part/)

Comment: Thanks for the info Clausen.

Answer (score 2):

With a little fiddling around, this seems to work well:

```
SELECT CAST(CONVERT(CHAR(17), bl.[time],113) AS varchar(17))
```

> Result given: 2011-11-22 12:14

The exact way I'm using it in my query as part of the **selection list** :

```
,CAST(CONVERT(CHAR(17), bl.[time],113) AS varchar(17))
+ '    (UTC +0)' AS [TIME]
```

> Gives me the result: 15 Dec 2017 06:43    (UTC +0)

Comment: `,CAST(CONVERT(CHAR(17), bl.[time],113) AS varchar(17))` is the solution to the result (`15 Dec 2017 06:43`) I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

**From SQL Server 2014, You can use Format function for this.**

for Ex.

```
 declare @Startdate datetime = '2020-11-07 15:27:50.713'

 set  @Startdate = Convert(datetime,FORMAT(@Startdate, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm'))


> Result is 
2020-11-07 15:27:00.000
```

Comment: Nice Option. But this should be used for small tables only. In larger tables, as in my case with 10 Million Rows with Index on datetime variable, this increased the query time from 2 seconds to 23. More here: https://sqlperformance.com/2015/06/t-sql-queries/format-is-nice-and-all-but

Answer (score 1):

If there is no milliseconds, than

```
DECLARE @dt datetime2 = '2011-11-22 12:14:58.000';
DECLARE @goalDt datetime2 = DATEADD(second,-DATEPART(second,@dt), @dt);
```

To remove a milliseconds part, add

```
SET @goalDt = DATEADD(millisecond,-DATEPART(millisecond,@goalDt ), goalDt dt);
```

Answer (score 1):

To Round Off it:

```sql
DECLARE @TheDate DATETIME;
SET @TheDate = '2019-1-2 12:14:58.400';

SELECT CAST(@TheDate AS SMALLDATETIME);
```

To just Truncate:

```sql
DECLARE @TruncTheDate DATETIME;
SET @TruncTheDate = '2019-1-2 12:14:58.400';

SELECT DATEADD(mi, DATEDIFF(mi, 0, @TruncTheDate), 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

select substring(cast(cast(getdate() as time(0)) as char(8)),0,6)

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @now DATETIME = GETUTCDATE()
SELECT @now = DATETIMEFROMPARTS(DATEPART(YEAR, @now),
                                DATEPART(MONTH, @now),
                                DATEPART(DAY, @now),
                                DATEPART(HOUR, @now),
                                DATEPART(MINUTE, @now),
                                0,
                                0)
```

Comment: You should add explanation.