# Ignore seconds and milliseconds FROM GETDATE() in SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

I wanted to remove/ignore the seconds and milliseconds coming from GETDATE() SQL function.
When I executed,

```
SELECT GETDATE()
```

output will be like

```
2015-01-05 14:52:28.557
```

I wanted to ignore seconds and milliseconds from above output. What is the optimize and best way to do this?

I have tried to do this by typecasting like this:

```
SELECT CAST(FORMAT(GETDATE(),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:0') AS datetime)
```

Is it is the correct and optimize way to do this?

Comment: What do you actually want to do? Simply format it in a particular way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [A way to extract from a DateTime value data without seconds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8896663/a-way-to-extract-from-a-datetime-value-data-without-seconds)

Comment: @ shree.pat18 I have a datetime DB column in which till minutes date is saving in database. Now, I wanted compare it with current system date, which I'm getting from getdate function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd either use the `DATEADD`/`DATEDIFF` trick that [Codo has shown](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28338137/15498) or just cast it to [`smalldatetime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms182418.aspx)<sup>1</sup>:

```
select CAST(GETDATE() as smalldatetime)
```

I'd avoid anything that involves round-tripping the value through a string.

<sup>1</sup>It may be appropriate, at this time, to change your schema to use this data type anyway, if seconds are always irrelevant.

Comment: @ Damien_The_Unbeliever, I think this is the best way to do it, just typecast into smalldatetime. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT dateadd(minute, datediff(minute, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
```

The query uses the fact that `DATEDIFF` return the number of minutes between two dates, ignoring the smaller units. `0` is a fixed date in the past.

It can be easily adapted to other time units.

Answer (score 0):

I think your way is fine if it works (looks like it should, but I haven't tested it.) There are lots of other possible approaches, too. Here's one:

```
select cast(convert(char(16), getdate(), 120) as datetime)
```