# How to compare two dates ignoring seconds in sql server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime

I have two dates in SQL Server

```
@dt1 = 2018-03-15 11:12:10
@dt2 = 2018-03-15 11:12:45
```

I want `(@dt1 = @dt2)`

This condition should be true.

In short, I want to ignore seconds and only consider date and hours & minutes.

How can I do it in SQL Server??

Comment: related : [way to extract from a DateTime value data without seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8896663/a-way-to-extract-from-a-datetime-value-data-without-seconds)

Answer (score 7):

All these answers rounding the values are ignoring that we can just ask for the difference in minutes between the two values and if it's 0, we know they occur within the same minute:

```
select CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(minute,@dt1,@dt2) = 0 THEN 'Equal' ELSE 'Not equal' END
```

This works because `DATEDIFF` counts *transitions*, which is often counter-intuitive to "human" interpretations - e.g. `DATEDIFF(minute,'10:59:59','11:00:01')` is going to return 1 rather than 0, despite the times only being 2 seconds apart - but this is exactly the interpretation you're seeking, where all smaller units within the datetime are ignored.

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you.

```
@dt1 = SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, yourcolumn), 0)
@dt2 = SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, yourcolumn), 0)

IF @dt1 = @dt2
BEGIN

END
```

Comment: It will be more effective and speedy.

Answer (score 2):

Compare datetimes both rounded down to the minute :

```
DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @d1, @d2)
```

This will be true if and only if the value differs by the minute.

Comment: Really no need to recreate dates, just compare the ints unless an index is in play.

Answer (score 1):

```
@dt1withoutsecs = DATETIMEFROMPARTS(year(@dt1), month(@dt1), day(@dt1), DATEPART(hh,@dt1), DATEPART(mi,@dt1), 0, 0)
@dt2withoutsecs = DATETIMEFROMPARTS(year(@dt2), month(@dt2), day(@dt2), DATEPART(hh,@dt2), DATEPART(mi,@dt2), 0, 0)
```

You should be able to compare those two

*Edit*: I went and actually tested it (sqlfiddle didn't want to work today):

[image: test]

Answer (score 0):

```sql
declare @dt1 datetime = '2018-03-15 11:12:10';
declare @dt2 datetime = '2018-03-15 11:12:45';

if convert(varchar,@dt1,0) = convert(varchar,@dt2,0)
print 'match';
else
print 'no match';
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has a few answers—including at least one that has been validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score -1):

Here is your solution:
[How can I truncate a datetime in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/923295/how-can-i-truncate-a-datetime-in-sql-server)

In short it depends on your version. In SQL server 2008 there is `cast(getDate as date)`

Comment: OP only wants to ignore seconds, not hour & minute

Comment: you're right. didn't see that. thanks for making that clear.